# get text from dragonfly speech recogtion engine

Tags: python, python-dragonfly

I would like to get the text recognized by the speech recognition engine dragonfly and get the text using python . Have tried using natlink but i want to make a server base application and get only the text recognized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use either Natlink or Windows Speech Recognition. No text gets recognized without a recognition engine. If you want to get the full recognized text, make a command with a Dictation element and nothing else in it. Map it to a Function action which does whatever you want with the results. Like so:

```
def myfunction(mycommand):
    mycommand = str(mycommand)
    '''do something ... '''

class MyRule(MappingRule):
    mapping = {
        "<mycommand>":            Function(myfunction)
    }
    extras = [ Dictation("mycommand") ]
    defaults = {"mycommand": None}
```

Comment: Can you provide me link to some sample codes or the complete code

Comment: Provided that you have Dragonfly installed and do the appropriate imports at the top of the file, this will get you the strings you need for your task. Are you asking how to take those strings and do stuff with them, or how to get the code in my answer running?